# IDs not sorting

Tags: php, mysql

I got an odd problem. Whenever I add a new entry to the database it gives it a higher id number, but somehow sees it as a lower number and puts it below the older ones.

And when sorting `DESC` in PHP I also get this order, does anybody know whats going wrong here?

I use `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY 'id' DESC");`to sort them, and it gives the same order as in the pic. (Not sure why i'm being downvoted here but ok..)

Pic: 
 [image]

Comment: So DESC sorting gives you `12, 11, 2, 1, 13, 14`?

Comment: Can you show Type  of id coulmn

Comment: How you are sorting DESC in php?

Comment: what is the type of column id

Comment: Yes I am sorting by: `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY 'id' DESC");` and it gives me 12, 11, 2,1,13,14

Comment: Could you please provide a SQL schema (or at least, type of id column)?

Comment: # = 1, name = id, type = int(11), Null = no, Default = none, Extra = AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY 'id' DESC
```

You are sorting by the *string* `'id'`, note the syntax highlighting when not within quotes. This means you get them in a random order. Remove the `'`. If you meant to escape the column `id` you should use back-ticks:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

When you insert data on the tables, it does not mean that the new number (or the highest) always on the lowest row. It randomly inserts the record. The only way you can sort it when you retrieve the rows in by using `ORDER BY` clause, example

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

So assume that ID is numeric. If you're ID is stored as string then you should *convert* it to numeric,

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY CAST(ID AS SIGNED) DESC
```

**UPDATE 1**

It should be

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

not

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY 'id' DESC");
```

what you have done was you have surrounded the `ID` with single quote forcing the server to read it as String and not `Numeric`

Comment: You're correct, but he says DESC ordering returns the same order (top-down I assume).

Comment: I used `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY 'id' DESC");` and that gives me the same order as in the DB

Comment: @iccthedral maybe his ID is stored as string, I updated the answer by adding `CAST` function to convert in to numeric.

Comment: @Coolcrab the reason why it is not ordering because you are wrapping it with single quote causing it to be string format. I think you mean backtick. **$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY `id` DESC");**

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are not using any `ORDER BY` clause, the order in PHPMyAdmin is *kind of random*. Indeed, new rows could take place of old ones.

I am curious how you *sort `DESC` in PHP* though.

Comment: I use `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY 'id' DESC");`

Answer (score 0):

Don't absolutely trust in GUI web interface because sometimes (not always) it bugs with session management, however you can run SQL Queries using it.

1- To run a SQL query, click on "SQL" on the navigation bar.

2- Enter your SQL in the box provided.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

3- Click "Go".